# bash script to trap all interupts

Tags: bash

so i have a simple lab exercise in class. Write and Interrupt/signal trapping program. this program will prompt user to guess the age of a grandmother. The user may guess as many times as possible. nothing will be able to terminate this program execpt when the user enters the right answer.
so my question is this. I have trapped ctrl_c but is there some "trick" or command i can use to trap ALL the interrupts or do i need to just make a statement for each signal i want to trap.

```
age=88

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c()
{
echo "**Trapped CTRL-C"

}

while [ 1 ]

do

echo "Please enter Grandmothers age. "
read ageGuess
echo $ageGuess
if [ $ageGuess == $age ]
then
    echo "Exiting!"
    exit
fi
```

done

Answer (score 1):

Afaik `trap xxx INT` should be enough you can read more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57940/trap-int-term-exit-really-necessary) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap), I will mention a few things about your script though:

The test command (`[`) uses `=` to compare two strings, not `==`.

You should double-quote all your variables unless you are sure what will happen if they are not quoted, consider this:

```
a=a
b=a
# This will work since `$a` and `$b` contains a value
if [ $a = $b ]; then 
  echo hello
fi
```

This will fail since $c is empty and the statement will evaluate to: `if [ = ]; then`

```
if [ $c = $d ]; then
  echo fail 
fi
```

You should use `true` or `:` in your while loop:

```
while :; do
```

You should usually always use `-r` in `read`, and remember the shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
age=88

trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c() {
  echo "**Trapped CTRL-C"
}

while :; do
  echo "Please enter Grandmothers age. "
  read -r ageGuess
  echo "$ageGuess"
  if [ "$ageGuess" = "$age" ]; then
    echo "Exiting!"
    exit
  fi
done
```

Actually the code could now use `#!/bin/sh` since it POSIX compatible.

Just note that you might want to use `printf "%s\n" "$user_input"` instead of `echo "$user_input"`

Comment: In really old shells you should use `[ x"$a" = x"$b" ]` to handle inputs starting with `-`